# Heap corruption detected in dynamic 2 D array

Tags: c++, data-structures, memory-management

I am getting heap corruption error while trying to free memory with delete

Here's code

```
char** split(char* inputstr, char delim, int& count){

char** ostr=NULL;
int numStr = 0;
int i=0,j,index=0;


while(inputstr[i]){ 

    if(inputstr[i++]==delim)
        numStr++;

}

if(inputstr[i-1]!=delim)
    numStr++;


count= numStr;
ostr = new char*[numStr];

i=0;
while(inputstr[i])
{
    j=i;
    while(inputstr[j] && inputstr[j] != delim)
        j++;

    ostr[index] = new char[j-i+1];

    //istr[j] = 0;

    strncpy(ostr[index], inputstr+i,j-i);

    ostr[index++][j-i]=0;

    i=j+1;

}

return ostr;

}

for(int i=0,countStr;i<_numComp;i++){

            char** _str = split(str[1+i],':',countStr);

            message.lastTransList.cmpName[i] = new char[strlen(_str[0])+1];
            strcpy(message.lastTransList.cmpName[i],_str[0]);
            message.lastTransList.price[i] = atof(_str[1]);

            for(int i=0; i<countStr;i++)
            {
                delete[] _str[i];    //this is working fine
                _str[i] = 0;

            }

            delete[] _str;     //exception is thrown at this line
        }
```

I am not able to find the problem. Please help !

Comment: Do you have a reason to use c-strings and raw arrays? `std::string` and `std::vector` would probably help you a lot here

Comment: You can indicate what the error exact is, what you have tried until now, and try to revert the code to a minimal failing (but compiling) example.

Comment: Did you consider running this program with valgrind?

Comment: I am using raw arrays because I cant use vectors in this project. The exact error is heap corruption, I tried debugging using breakpoints, The error is appearing on line delete[] _str, rest all is working correctly. No, I dont know nothing about Valgrind. Should I use it. How it will help?

Comment: Valgrind will help pinpoint the source of your heap corruption (down to the line number in most cases.)  It's the perfect tool for this use case if you're on a platform where it's supported.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see any error, there could be something wrong with your indexing that's causing a buffer overrun in the split function that's caught only when you try to delete the char** array.

How about converting to std::string and std::vectors like carlpett recommends (it's a good recommendation).

something like this:

```
void split(const std::string& str_, char delimiter_, std::vector<std::string>& result_)
{
  std::string token;
  std::stringstream stream(str_);
  while( std::getline(stream, token, delimiter_) ) result_.push_back(token);
}
```

Then, you just call it with your string, delimiter and an empty std::vector and end up with a populated vector of substrings.  You don't have to use new/delete and worry about the memory issues.

Comment: Why do you pass result as an argument instead of returning it? Even better, recommend boost, that has split on token built in.

Comment: We are returning the split-ted string as 2D character array and passing the number of strings as an argumnet by reference as we cant return two things.

Comment: @KillianDS - In that example I'm passing the result as argument because I want to avoid the copies that'd occur if used as a return value.

Comment: @brandx: return value optimization is likely to be applied, and at least give the C++11 alternative using rvalue references then. This is awful design that is the reason of so many unreadable APIs.

Comment: @KillianDS - why rely on the compiler doing RVO? I'd much rather have the parameter as I provided here for the potential of reusing the vector elsewhere.  As for C++11, it's cool and all, but C++11 was days old when the question was asked.  If you have a C++11 alternative, please provide as an alternative answer.